# What is wrong with my React.js code for blog comment feature

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I created a comment feature in my node.js blog application. I am using Mongodb data base. Everything works fine in postman. I can create new comments. However, I am trying to replicate the same in my client side via React.js. I think I have exhausted all my ideas. Here is the error message I keep getting each time I try to create a new comment from client side: This error is console.log from the catch(err) in backend.

```
undefined
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"
```

**Post Model**

```
//creating the user models for the database

const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
   
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
       
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
    postPhoto:{
        type: String,
        required:false,
    },
   username:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    categories:{
       type: Array,
    },
   comments: [{
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Comment',
         unique: true,
       }]
   
   }, {timestamps: true},

  );
 //exporting this schema
 module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**Comment Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose to be used
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
    commentdescription:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
    },
   author:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User',
        
    },
   
 
 }, {timestamps: true}
);
//exporting this schema
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**create new comment and push to post codes**

```
//creating catergory logic

 router.post("/posts/:id/comment", async (req, res) =>{
 const newComment = new Comment(req.body);//we create a new comment for the database
    
 try{
    //we need to try and catch the new comment and save it

    const currentPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)//we need to find the post  that has the comment via the id
        currentPost.comments.push(newComment)//we need to push the comment into the post

        await newComment.save();
        await currentPost.save()//we saved the new post with the comment
    res.status(200).json(currentPost)
   }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
 })
```

**What I have written in React**

```
const [commentdescription, setCommentDescription] = useState('')
const [postId, setPostId] = useState()
 
  //function to create comment
 const handleComment = async ()=>{
 const newComment = {
    _id: postId,
    author: user._id,
    commentdescription,
};

try{
    await axios.post("/posts/:id/comment", newComment);
     
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
 }
```

Everything works fine in postman. I know I am missing something in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass actual ID to that POST request url.

```js
await axios.post(`/posts/${postId}/comment`, newComment);
```

When POSTing to `/posts/:id/comment`, your parsed value (req.params.id) will literally be `:id`, which cannot be casted as `ObjectId`.

Comment: yea, you are right. I actually sorted it out like this  await axios.post("/posts/"+ path + "/comment", newComment);